# asp:Hyperlink is not clickable

Tags: asp.net

I am missing something very basic here. I have a simple asp:Hyperlink. It displays as I anticipate, however, it is not clickable. In the Developer Tools in the browser, the correct hyperlink is shown and is clickable.

```
            <asp:DetailsView ID="ProductLink" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="SKU" DataSourceID="SqlProductLink" GridLines="None">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div id="Div1" runat="server" visible='<%# Eval("SKU") != DBNull.Value %>'>
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("SKU", "~/Selected.aspx?SKU={0}") %>' Target="_new" Text="Product Information"></asp:HyperLink>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Fields>
            </asp:DetailsView>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds themselves as flabbergasted as I was, I found the culprit... a pseudo element with absolute positioning. Once I removed that, everything worked as designed.

Cheers